# G+ Comment plugin Share button

Tags: google-plus

i need help to remove Google plus, share button, follow button, comment plugin,
from my Blogger websit.

Comment: This post is not well structured. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

If you have those G+ widgets present on your blog site, that means that your Blogger.com blog is linked to the Google-plus account. As you know Blogger.com is part of Google.

To unlink them you can go to settings and click on `Revert to blogger profile`

Video tutorial can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h8aIGsXax3A

Also be advised that Google-plus will be disabled by Google in near future as the platform is empty, not used, hated and there are some huge security risks there. Official article about dicontinuing G+ can be found here: https://blog.google/technology/safety-security/project-strobe/